# AD users can’t login to specific workstation

Tags: active-directory

I have two workstations that no AD user can log into. The message received when trying is that the username or password is incorrect.

No bad login attempt is recorded in AD.

I did find that Test-ComputerSecureChannel returned $false. So I did a repair in that and now it returns $true. But users are still not able to login on these specific machines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is in the System and Security event logs on the endpoints? And the text output of `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com` ?

Comment: @GregAskew nothing interesting in those logs at all. At least looking through my RMM. System just has some information about time updates and nothing else for the past 15 mintues while I was trying to log in. Security just has some success logs. No errors. nltest looks normal. Returns a valid DC, appropriate domain and forest. nothing looks off.